# webscraping: missing href attribute - simulate mouse clicks for webscraping necessary?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

For a fun webscraping project, I want to collect NHL data from ttps://www.nhl.com/stats/teams.

There is a clickable Excel Export tag which I can find using `selenium` and `bs4`.

Unfortunately, this is where it ends:
Since there is no `href` attribute it seems that I cannot access the data.

I got what I wanted by using `pynput` to simulatie a mouseclick, but I wonder:

Could I do that differently? If feels so clumsy.

-> the tag with the Export Icon can be found here :

```
a class="styles__ExportIcon-sc-16o6kz0-0 dIDMgQ"
```

-> Here is my code

```
`import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'somepath\chromedriver.exe')

URL = 'https://www.nhl.com/stats/teams'

driver.get(URL)
html = driver.page_source  # DOM with JavaScript execution complete
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
body = soup.find('body')
print(body.prettify())


mouse = Controller()

time.sleep(5) # Sleep for 5 seconds until page is loaded
mouse.position = (1204, 669) # thats where the icon is on my screen
mouse.click(Button.left, 1) # executes download`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `href` attribute, download is triggert via JS. While working with `selenium` find your element and use `.click()` to download the file:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h2>a').click()
```

Used [`css selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) here to get direct children `<a>` of the `<h2>` or select it directly by class starting with `styles__ExportIcon`:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[class^="styles__ExportIcon"]').click()
```

##### Example

You may have to deal with onetrust banner, so click it first and than download the sheet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://www.nhl.com/stats/teams'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#onetrust-reject-all-handler').click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h2>a').click()
```

Comment: Thank you HedgeHog, that surely is the way to go. Code works until the last line, but I can't find the element using your code just yet. I did not stumble over that notation "h2 > a" and don't know how I would modify to get my Icon.

Comment: Added some references where you can dive deeper into.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Great first time "asked a question" experience. Thumbs up!